# RNSVGTSpan was not found in UI manager in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg-charts

I got the below error frequently.

ERROR : Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGTSpan" was not found in the UIManager.

this is my dependencies:{
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
"react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
}

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error in the iOS version of react-native app. I had forgotten to do `pod install` at ios directory and rebuild the app in Xcode. This worked for me.